# Outlook 2010 with Exchange 2003 account freezes with event ID 515 in security event log

Tags: exchange-2003, outlook-2010

My Outlook 2010 freezes a couple of times per day. I am connected to a Exchange 2003 server. Sometimes, when I try to send an email or open an appointment, the interface completely freezes. After a few seconds a balloon pops up saying:Outlook is contacting Server.network.local (where 'Server' is the primary domain controller and not the Exchange server). 
I checked the event log of that server and I found out that every time my Outlook freezes, three notices are written to the Security Event log:

> Event Type:   Success Audit Event
>   Source:   Security Event
>   Category: System Event  Event ID: 515
>   Date:  4/8/2011 Time:  4:45:26 PM
>   User:  NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
>   Computer: Server Description: A
>   trusted logon process has registered
>   with the Local Security Authority.
>   This logon process will be trusted to
>   submit logon requests.
>
> Logon Process Name:   KSecDD
>
> For more information, see Help and
>   Support Center at
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.
>
> Event Type:   Success Audit Event
>   Source:   Security Event
>   Category: System Event  Event ID: 515
>   Date:  4/8/2011 Time:  4:45:25 PM
>   User:  NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
>   Computer: Server Description: A
>   trusted logon process has registered
>   with the Local Security Authority.
>   This logon process will be trusted to
>   submit logon requests.
>
> Logon Process Name:   KSecDD
>
> For more information, see Help and
>   Support Center at
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.
>
> Event Type:   Success Audit Event
>   Source:   Security Event
>   Category: System Event  Event ID: 515
>   Date:  4/8/2011 Time:  4:45:25 PM
>   User:  NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
>   Computer: Server Description: A
>   trusted logon process has registered
>   with the Local Security Authority.
>   This logon process will be trusted to
>   submit logon requests.
>
> Logon Process Name:   Winlogon\MSGina
>
> For more information, see Help and
>   Support Center at
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.

Who can help me solving the freezing Outlook?

Comment: Couple suggestions: 1.Run dcdiag/netdiag on your DCs, validate all is good, 2.Validate that on your workstation you have DNS servers for your domain. 3.Check that the time is properly synced between your workstation, Exchange server and DCs.

Comment: @Vick All tests are either passed or skipped when run dcdiag and netdiag on the DC's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it's been solved by enabling Cached Exchange Mode in the account settings tab.